# remove appendElement javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that when the user will click the *Add button* a Textbox will appear.
But what I want to implement is to remove the textbox that was appended individually by clicking a button:

```
<div class="form_group">
   <div id="p_scents">
      <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="addAffiliate()">+ Add Merchant ID</a><br>
      <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="deleteAffiliate()">+ Remove Merchant ID</a><br>
      <p></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript is:

```
function addAffiliate() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" required="true" id="p_scnt" size="30" class="form-control" name="merchant[]" value="" placeholder="Input MerchantID" /></label>  </p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
}
```

My `deleteAffiliate` function is where I want to delete a single textbox that was appended before.

Comment: [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) with jquery and [remove()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp) with javascript

Comment: But what I want to add is to remove? o.O

Comment: It's little bit unclear.

Comment: im sorry for making it unclear..already edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are appending several elements with same id "p_scnt" and you should avoid that. Change the function to:

```
function addAffiliate()
{
   var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
   var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
   // here we change the id to p_scnt_ + iterator
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" required="true" id="p_scnt_'+i+'" size="30" class="form-control" name="merchant[]" value="" placeholder="Input MerchantID" /></label>  </p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;

}
```

Then change the remove function to remove the last-child of parent.

```
function deleteAffiliate()
{
    $('#p_scents p:last-child').remove();
}
```